# json parse issue while posting to api

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file. I want to replace the value field with dynamic variables. 
If my app fetches "9.3" I want it to be replaced (2.3 to 9.3) in the json file. 
I tried this approach using placeholders
**JSON.stringify(jsonFile).split("{bloodGlucoseValue}").join(9.3)** 
This method messed up my json file. When I use this approach I am unable to POST this json to my api. It throws "Failed to parse request body as JSON resource...." error.

How else can I do this?

```
{
    "resourceType" : "Bundle",
    "type" : "transaction",
    "entry" : [
        {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:patient",
            "resource" : {
                "resourceType" : "Patient",
                "name" : [
                    {
                        "given": ["ABC"],
                        "family": "Uni"
                    }
                        ]
                    },
                "request" : {
                    "method" : "POST",
                    "url" : "Patient"
                }
           },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "resourceType" : "Observation",
                "code" : {
                    "coding" : [
                        {
                            "system": "http://loinc.org",
                            "code": "15074-8",
                            "display": "Glucose [Moles/volume] in Blood"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "type" : "Patient",
                    "reference" : "urn:uuid:patient"
                },
                "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": 2.3,
                    "unit": "mmol/l",
                    "system": "http://unitofmeasure.org",
                    "code": "mmol/L"
                }
            },
            "request" : {
                "method" : "POST"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not convert json file to json object and manipulate value. Then you can change it to string and save in file or do whatever you like.
e.g.

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
jsonObject.entry[1].resource.valueQuantity.value = 9.3;
JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

This is just an example. Please put checks as you to avoid exceptions